# Calculate the following limit: $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\cos x \ln x}{\ln(e^x - e)} $

Tags: limits

I have tried using l'Hopital's, which is a recursive nightmare, and setting the expression to y and finding the limit of ln(y), but that didn't go anywhere either.

Comment: The top part goes to zero as $\ln(1) = 0$ and the bottom part goes to $\ln(e-1) \neq 0$.

Comment: @Marc Made a little mistake in the question, that would've been too easy!

Comment: Are the conditions to use L'Hospital's theorem met? This limit does not seem to be of the type $\frac00$ or $\frac\infty\infty$, does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, assuming your function is $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, this function only exists when $x > 1$ due to the presence of logarithms. So it only makes sense to consider the right limit.

Now, consider your limit. If we just "evaluate" in $1$ (this is terrible notation!):
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\cos(x) \ln(x)}{\ln(e^x - e)}  = \frac{\cos(1) \cdot \ln(1)}{\ln(0)} = \frac{\cos(1) \cdot 0}{-\infty} = 0$$

Not that you MAY NOT use de l'Hôpital's rule, since your limit is not of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Answer (score 1):

The denominator will not be real if $x\to1^-$

$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{\cos x \ln x}{\ln(e^x - e)}=\lim_{x\to1^+}\cos x\cdot\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{\ln x}{\ln(e^x - e)}$$

Now
$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{\ln x}{\ln(e^x - e)}=\dfrac{\ln1}{\ln(e-e)}=\dfrac0{-\infty}=0$$